# Swap first two elements in array that aren't sorted

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to write code that looks for the first two elements in an array that are out of order and swaps them. I wrote this code but am only printing out 3 when I run it. Can someone help me rewrite my code for it to work?

```
arr = [5, 22, 29, 39, 19, 51, 78, 96, 84]
i = 0
while (i < arr.size - 1 and arr[i] < arr[i + 1])
  i = i + 1
end
puts i
arr[i] = arr[i + 1]
arr[i + 1] = arr[i]
```

Comment: You have a problem with the element swap, as `arr[i+1] = arr[i] = arr[i+1]`, so `arr[i+1]` is unchanged. You need to use a temporary variable or (better) use [multiple assignment](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Assignment) (aka *parallel assignment*) as I've done in my answer.  Also, if `arr` is fully ordered to begin with you will raise an exception when `i = arr.size - 1`, as you will compare the last element, `arr[i]` with `arr[arr.size]`, the latter being `nil`.

Answer (score 5):

You could write the following:

```
arr = [5, 22, 29, 39, 19, 51, 78, 96, 84]
```

```
i = (0..arr.size-2).find { |i| arr[i] > arr[i+1] }
  #=> 3
arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i] unless i.nil?
  #=> [19, 39]
arr
  #=> [5, 22, 29, 19, 39, 51, 78, 96, 84]
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your current code is:

```
arr[i] = arr[i + 1]
arr[i + 1] = arr[i]
```

Where you set `arr[i]` equal to `arr[i + 1]`, then repace the content of `arr[i + 1]` with `arr[i]` (which is set to `arr[i + 1]`). This sets both the elements to the content of `arr[i + 1]`. You can use a temporary variable to hold the previous value of `arr[i]`.

```
tmp = arr[i]
arr[i] = arr[i + 1]
arr[i + 1] = tmp
```

A cleaner way of doing this is using [multiple assignment](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Assignment).

```
arr[i], arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1], arr[i]
```

Which removes the need for the temporary variable.

---

Taking some inspiration from the answers of [Cary Swoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58143762/3982562) and [iGian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58144587/3982562). Here is another refactored way of finding the index and swapping the values.

```
arr = [5, 22, 29, 39, 19, 51, 78, 96, 84]
```

```
i = arr.each_cons(2).find_index { |a, b| a > b }
arr[i, 2] = arr[i, 2].reverse if i

arr #=> [5, 22, 29, 19, 39, 51, 78, 96, 84]
```

Comment: Could I ask you a question to check whether my interpretation is in the right direction? `.each_cons(2)` method is used to find out first two elements which are out of order. `find_index` is used to find the index of those two elements. `arr[1,2].reverse if i` - How does it work? I understand that if the first element is larger, it swaps the position - larger element (39) is replaced with smaller element value (19). Is my understanding correct? Thanks!

Comment: @FuriousCodeNinja `each_cons(2)` transforms the collection from `[1, 2, 4, 3]` to `[[1, 2], [2, 4], [4, 3]]`. I then use `find_index { |a, b| a > b }` to find the index where the elements are out of order. In the case of `[[1, 2], [2, 4], [4, 3]]` it would return `2`, since `[4, 3]` matches the `{ |a, b| a > b }` criteria. If an match is found `i` will be set, if no match is found `i` will be `nil`, so `if i` makes sure we only swap elements if `i` is found. `arr[i, 2]` creates a new array, starting from `i` and taking `2` elements. You replace this part of the array with the reversed version.

Comment: Thanks @3limin4t0r! taking `2` makes sense to me now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) coupled with [Enumerable#each_winth_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) for getting the pairs and their indexes(*).
Then [Enumerable#find](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) the first index of pair in reversed order, [Object#then](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Object.html#method-i-then) modify the original array inserting the swapped pair:

```
arr = [1,2,3,5,4]

arr.each_cons(2).with_index.find { |(a, b), i| a > b }
   .then { |e, i| arr[i..i+1] = e.reverse if i }

arr
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

---

(*) How it works:

```
arr.each_cons(2).with_index.to_a
#=> [[[1, 2], 0], [[2, 3], 1], [[3, 5], 2], [[5, 4], 3]]
```

Note: use [Object#yield_self](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.6/Object.html#method-i-yield_self) for older Ruby instead of Object#then